# Apache Options -Indexes for sub directories

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Per [How can I prevent people from looking at a listing of files in parent directory if I haven't uploaded index.html?](https://serverfault.com/questions/283758/how-can-i-prevent-people-from-looking-at-a-listing-of-files-in-parent-directory) I can see how to disable listing of files if there is no index.* file.

How can i allow file listing for the root directory, but not any other sub directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged the question `.htaccess`, you could do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file on Apache 2.4:

```
# Default - Directory listings disabled (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

# Override - Allow directory listings for the root only
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/'">
    Options +Indexes
</If>
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally sub directories will inherit the same settings you apply to their parent directory in Apache. And, as far as I know, you can't change that and there doesn't exist a way to limit the scope of directives to only a single directory level.

That means that you need to:

- set the option/directive you want on the parent directory
- change/override/negate that option/directive for all (current and new) subdirectories.

Rather than doing that for every subdirectory individually it is  easiest to that do that with the [`DirectoryMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directorymatch) directive.

In you main httpd.conf (or an include) set

```
<Directory "/path/to/example.com/">
  # enable directory listings
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>


<DirectoryMatch "/path/to/example.com/.*/">
  # Disable directory listings for all sub directories of /path/to/example.com/
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

(not tested)